# How can i add a second time zone?

Tags: 11.10, time, clock, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a world clock indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52507/how-can-i-get-a-world-clock-indicator)

In 11.04 i had a second time zone in the Clock/Date Dropdown. In 11.10 there seems to be no obvious way to do this, is there one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Time and Date drop-down, click "Time and Date Settings".

Click on the "Clock" tab.

Enable the check-box "Time in Other Locations".

Click "Choose Locations". Then, add as many cities and regions as you want :)

**The times for those regions will be shown in the dropdown.**