# World clock indicator on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, clock

Looking at the old [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52507/how-can-i-get-a-world-clock-indicator) to this question, it's clear that the UI was changed as it no longer provides a way to add multiple time zones using the settings page.
I'd like to see an indicator of the time in multiple countries instead of just my local time.
Is there a way to achieve this on Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: @dobey, looking at the question from 2012 and the upvoted answer, it doesn't cover or address the solution for Artful 17.10.

Comment: the actual answer is not just to install gnome-clocks, but most importantly, perform a logout and re-login! see https://askubuntu.com/a/969135/99871

Comment: If something changed with regards to the extension or answer, then the answer really should be updated there. Having multiple questions and answers for every slight change in behavior for new releases, only serves to create more confusion.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 12 and 17.10 use different launchers, it might be better to separate answers based on the release and what's specifically supported on that release.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the question I flagged this as a duplicate of, with the question you linked in your question. They are not the same thing. Your question is "how do I get multiple clocks in the panel in gnome-shell." It doesn't matter if that's on Ubuntu 12.04 or 17.10. There should be one question/answer for that, and if the answer needs updating for minor changes in newer releases, it should be updated, and as old releases become EOL, answers should be updated to remove no longer useful information for supported releases.

Comment: you are correct, they are two separate question. the questions you linked is indeed a duplicate, but it's not well written because it requires the user to know they are using gnome-shell (which they don't if they just install Ubuntu they are unaware of the name of that particular software component). it also lacks a complete answer, which makes it useless unless you already know the answer, which I didn't at the time of writing this question.